# HashMap<Object, Boolean> toString problem

Tags: java, hashmap, tostring

I am having a Map of type HashMap.

I am trying to iterate over the map and for every entry, for which the boolean flag is set to true, I am trying to print the corresponding key value.

I am able to achieve this. However, instead of printing the String "key" values, it prints String objects. I tried casting it, using the .toString() function. Nothing solved it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,S.

Comment: The problem description of "printing string objects instead of string key values" does not make any sense. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your followup suggests that the values in your Map are not of type String and are not of a type that has overridden toString, which is why, when you call toString, you get a value like "com.f5.lunaui.emproto.reports.Device_Sri@334003".

In Device_Sri, you should override the toString method to return the String you want:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "em_device90-36";
}
```

Of course, you'll probably want to calculate the value "em_device90-36" from the fields of the Device_Sri class.

Answer (score 5):

You want to iterate over the Map's entrySet:

```
Set< Map.Entry<String, Boolean> > es = map.entrySet();
```

That's a set, so you can iterate over it:

```
for( Map.Entry<String, Boolean> v : es ) {
   if( v.getValue() ) { // auto-unboxing
       System.out.println(v.getKey());
   }
}
```

Simplifying:

```
for( Map.Entry<String, Boolean> v : map.entrySet() ) {
   if( v.getValue() ) {
       System.out.println(v.getKey());
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it more efficiently than with get() and the key set. This is the answer I was typing when IE crashed on me.

Comment: You should stop using IE @ArtB

Comment: I did try something similar to what you have suggested. But I still get the String objects printed instead of the string. You could scroll down and see my comment to know what I mean by String objects.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
for(String key : map.keySet()){
  if(map.get(key)){
    System.out.println(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't useful. You're saying: "For every key, k, in the map, if map.get( that key k ), print that key k". So you'll print every key, regardless of its (in this case Boolean) value. Moreover, `  if(map.get(key)){` is illegal in Java; your comparison to null, unlike in C/C++ must be explicit: `if(map.get(key) != null ){`. But further, map.get returns null both if the key doesn't exist OR if the key's value is null (for maps that allow null keys).

Comment: @tpdi I'm not comparing to null...the values in map are of type Boolean.  Java will auto unbox these for me, so the only values that will be printed are when the value associated with the key is True.  I don't have to worry about the key not existing because I'm explicitly iterating over only the keys (well unless there is some weird concurrency stuff going on).  There is a tiny risk of getting a null point exception when Java tries to unbox, but that would only happen if there is an explicit mapping from key to null.

Comment: @tpdi You clearly understand from your own answer that Java will auto-unbox that, so why did you think it wouldn't work here?  I didn't show the declaration of map, but obviously it's of type `HashMap<String, Boolean>` since OP explicitly mentioned that in the question.  Obviously my solution wouldn't work if the values were not of type `Boolean`, but it was obvious that they were...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Map<String, Boolean> myMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
myMap.put("one", true);
myMap.put("second", false);

for (String key : myMap.keySet()) {
  if (myMap.get(key)) {
    System.out.println(key + " --> " + myMap.get(key));
  }
}
```

Comment: OP said he is only interested in printing when the value is true.

Comment: Since you are using both the key and the value at the same time, it is better to use an EntrySet `for( Entry<String, Boolean> entry : myMap.entrySet() )`

Comment: @wolf 'better' is debatable. You will have a marginal performance gain (avoiding rehashing, but by definition that should be a fast operation) but the code is much more readable in @CarlosZ's version, and I consider an increase in readability to be superior to a marginal speed increase. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<String, Boolean> deviceChecked = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
deviceChecked = checkMap;

Set entry = deviceChecked.entrySet();
    Iterator i = entry.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry ent = (Map.Entry)i.next();
    if(ent.getValue()){
        result = result + (String)ent.getKey() + ", ";
    }
}
System.out.println("result is " +result);
return result;
```

I am trying to print the key only if the corresopnding boolean value is true. Something like the code above. In this, the result value does not contain the string and it turn prints the object.
I should get the value to be printed as  "em-device90-36". But, instead I get this printed

> com.f5.lunaui.emproto.reports.Device_Sri@334003

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You can (and should) edit your original question whenever you need to instead of posting your code in an answer. :-)

Comment: @Azure, thanks for pointing that out. I shall try to follow that tip in the future.

Comment: Your cast `(String)ent.getKey()` should fail, and throw a ClasscastException if the Map's key is not a String. However, this line (without a cast) would NOT throw: `result = result + ent.getKey() + ", ";` That's because String operator+ is overloaded, and calls toString on its second operand, as if you had written this `result = result + ent.getKey().toString + ", "; This is safe because all objects have a toString, and because String operator+ also has overloads for all primitive types, which convert them to Strings. The result you're getting looks like Object.toString is being called (more)

Comment: (continued) which suggests two things: your actual code doesn't have the explicit cast, and your map's key isn't really a String. The easy fix is to find the type of the actual key, and override its toString() method to return whatever string representation you think that class ought to return. Also, your line `private Map deviceChecked = new HashMap(); deviceChecked = checkMap;` creates and thgen throws away the new HashMap; you just need the reference (deviceChecked) here.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, you'll get a null pointer exception if the value is null.

```
if (e.getValue()) { ... }
```

This is because the value is a `Boolean` and will be unboxed to a `boolean`. It's equivalent to `e.getValue().booleanValue()`.

If you want to guard against the value being null, then use

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(e.getValue()) { ... }
```